# Hover Fade In And Out

Tags: javascript, css

Sir!, I Have A Question!
Is It Possible When You Hover Some Table Or Images, Will Be Fade In-Out-In-Out And So On.  And It Won't Stop Unless You Point Out The Hover? In CSS Or JS Please Thank You!

Comment: Capitol Letters Aren't Needed On Every Word.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, I missed that you wanted a pulsing effect perhaps like the old **blink** tag.  This updated example uses CSS animation, but there are other alternatives as well.

```css
@keyframes pulse {
    from { opacity: 1 }
    to { opacity: 0 }
}

.fade:hover {
    animation-name: pulse;
    animation-duration: 500ms;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="fade">Fade On Hover</div>
```

Comment: For as awful as the question is, it's pretty obvious that the OP is looking for the fade in/out to continue while you hover over an element and stop only when leaving it.

Comment: lol, for how terrible the question is, it was not clear to me that a pulse effect was desired.  I guess I deserve your downvote for attempting to help at all.

Comment: Questions as bad as this one should be fixed/clarified/expanded by the OP before trying to score points. The OP also has a responsibility to show what they've tried.